# Jenkins fails to clean workspace before build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to setup Jenkins running inside docker container and also being able to run containers there.

When I run first build all works great but when I run second one I am hitting following problem.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Here is the log from pipeline

```
Started by user Vit @ Jarmill
Replayed #4
Connecting to https://api.github.com using admin/****** (GitHub Access      Token)
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 382099092e83938b97a09ec5c8d627dd7456411d
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/iamwtk_site_master-  E6LR65PLWYZWNGUMZKPLCLOJ337SJ4G4F2WDI7TROT63NGV36NEQ
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)

[Pipeline] checkout

 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10

Fetching changes from the remote Git repository

> git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/iamwtk/iamwtk_site.git # timeout=10

Cleaning workspace

> git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10

Resetting working tree

> git reset --hard # timeout=10

> git clean -fdx # timeout=10

ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/iamwtk/iamwtk_site.git
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:888)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1155)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:85)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:75)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git clean -fdx" returned status code 1:

stdout: Removing front_end_server@tmp/


stderr: warning: failed to remove front_end_server/dist/server.js

warning: failed to remove front_end_server/dist/client/views/index.ejs

// and many more ....

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2002)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1970)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1966)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1597)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1609)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.clean(CliGitAPIImpl.java:787)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clean(GitAPI.java:311)
at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.CleanBeforeCheckout.decorateFetchCommand(CleanBeforeCheckout.java:30)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:884)
... 13 more

[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // stage

[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // node

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline


GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result


ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

Finished: FAILURE
```

I started container with following settings:

```
docker volume create --name data_jenkins
docker run --name jenkins -d -v data_jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

I already installed docker inside the container with daemon linking via volume to host machine daemon.
I set jenkins user to docker group to be able to run docker commands without sudo.

I am quite sure this must be problem of permissions I just really cannot find where. Already spent all day on this, hope somebody could point me right direction.

Comment: Why do you think that this is a Docker problem? I only see that `git clean -fdx` fails.

Comment: Never said it must be docker problem, it was problem of permissions in workspace directory, where git wasn't able to clean workspace. Took me some time but, fixed it already.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with permissions in workspace directory where the build was stored.

Changed permissions to allow jenkins user to rwx and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this:

```
 stage('delete files from workspace') {
  steps {
    sh 'ls -l'
    sh 'sudo rm -rf ./*'
  }
}
```

as one of the steps before the scm checkout and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you need to clean your workspace

1.copy workspace path(you can copy path of your workspace from console output of your job) ex:- /opt/jenkins/workspace/job_name

2.Open shell or ssh to Jenkins Instance(In case of VM or EC2 instance)

3. rm -rf /opt/jenkins/workspace/job_name
   or (if getting permission denied error)
   sudo rm -rf /opt/jenkins/workspace/job_name